# Binding property with parent ViewModel

Tags: wpf, viewmodel

Please refer to [How can I tell my DataTemplate to bind to a property in the PARENT ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026342/how-can-i-tell-my-datatemplate-to-bind-to-a-property-in-the-parent-viewmodel/18717026?noredirect=1#comment27579086_18717026)

I have similar problem... But this solution didn't work for me. I have a MainViewModel which has an observable collection of another view model say View1/ViewModel1. This view has a tree control and I need context menu for the tree. My main view has a menu. Those main menu and context menu are connected. So how can I bind the context menu commands to the main viewmodel's properties?

Answer (score 22):

Basically, you need to use a `RelativeSource` binding. The standard way is to find an ancestor (or parent) of the control of a particular type:

```
{Binding DataContext.PropertyName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourViewsNamespace:YourParentView}}}
```

Assuming that your parent view has a view model set to its `DataContext`, this binding will access it... the `DataContext` is the `DataContext` of the view, eg. the view model that is set as the `DataContext`. So, the `PropertyName` property is a public property from that view model.

Regarding the part of your question that has been asked so many times before, please see the following links (or just search online):

[Context Menus in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html)

[Binding ContextMenu to its logical Parent](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/patl-closed/archive/2007/02/01/Binding-ContextMenu-to-its-logical-Parent.aspx)

Comment: I have tried your solution..But it didnt give me the answer. I gone through your refernce sites also..But they too didnt help me. I tried in the following way............  
                <ContextMenu  >
                    <MenuItem x:Name="CopyItem" Header="Copy" Command="{Binding DataContext.CopyCmnd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Views:MainPanel}}}"  />
                    
                </ContextMenu>

Answer (score 0):

```
1. ParentViewModel has NavigateRecordCommand

2. Parentview has the DataContext Set to my ParentViewModel.

<UserControl x:Class="SampleProject.UI.ParentView"

<Grid>
    ....
<!--User control is here-->
    <local:NavigationControl  Grid.Row="1" />
    ....
</Grid>


3. Child Control as below. Not bounded to its ViewModel. Bounded to Parent Views DataContext i.e. ParentViewModel.

    <UserControl x:Class="SampleProject.UI.NavigationControl"
    ...
    ...
     xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:SampleProject.UI">

    <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateRecordCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Local:ParentView}}"
            CommandParameter="MoveFirst"/>
```