# Caliburn.Micro binding parent property in Child View. ( UWP )

Tags: binding, uwp, caliburn.micro

in Caliburn.Micro, I want to bind Parent property in Child View(ViewModel).

First is simple example.

This is Child View(XAML).

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Bg7Uwp1.Views.App.DerLayout.Der2View"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls" 
xmlns:micro="using:Caliburn.Micro"
xmlns:local="using:Bg7Uwp1.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Name="RootDer2">

<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.hello, ElementName=RootDer2}"/>
```

This is Child ViewModel.

```
public class Der2ViewModel : Conductor<Screen>
{
    public Der2ViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

This is parent View Model.

```
public string _hello = "HELLOWORLD!";
    public string hello
    {
        get { return _hello; }
        set
        {
            this.Set(ref _hello, value);
        }
    }
```

and this is parent View.

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Bg7Uwp1.Views.App.SpectrumView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls" 
xmlns:micro="using:Caliburn.Micro"
xmlns:local="using:Bg7Uwp1.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Name="Root"
d:DesignHeight="800"
d:DesignWidth="1000">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" 
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Above is just example. I used simple. and I want to bind without "x:Name". because "TextBlock" is final target to bind. I want to bind a custom control in ChildView.

This is my current CustomControl in Child View.

```
     <local:SensorMeter

        x:Name="DerRMeter"  
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        DerThreashold1Svh="{Binding DerMeters[1].DerThreashold1Svh, ElementName=RootDer2}"
        DerThreashold2Svh="{Binding DerMeters[1].DerThreashold2Svh, ElementName=RootDer2}"
        DerSvh="{Binding DerMeters[1].DerSvh, ElementName=RootDer2}"
        Title="{Binding DataContext.DerMeters[1].Title, ElementName=RootDer2}"
        connectionDeviceStatusEnum="{Binding DerMeters[1].connectionDeviceStatusEnum, ElementName=RootDer2}"
        ticketThresholdType="{Binding DerMeters[1].ticketThresholdType, ElementName=RootDer2}"
        device="{Binding DerMeters[1].device, ElementName=RootDer2}"
        micro:Message.Attach="[Event DoubleTapped]=[Action Click_DoubleTapped(1)];[Event Tapped]=[Action Click_Tapped(1)]"    

        />
```

This is my current Parent View Model.

```
public ObservableCollection<DerMeter> DerMeters
    {
        get { return _derMeters; }
        set
        {
            this.Set(ref _derMeters, value);
        }
    }
```

**Question**

How to bind "Parent property" to Child View ??

I found some helpful links.. but I can not make yet...

- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972934/uwp-equivalent-function-to-findancestor-in-uwp/43399114#43399114)
- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861612/how-to-do-relativesource-mode-find-ancestor-or-equivalent-in-uwp)
- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026342/how-can-i-tell-my-datatemplate-to-bind-to-a-property-in-the-parent-viewmodel/18717026?noredirect=1#comment27579086_18717026)
- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717241/binding-property-with-parent-viewmodel)

Comment: Could you please share a [MCVE] that can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've posted an answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/483), but the gist of it is that if you're using the out of the box `Screen` and `Conductor` classes then the view model will have a `Parent` property which you can use to create bindings to a view models parent conductor's properties.