# WPF MVVM Binding to parent view's ViewModel property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two views:

- ShellView - DataContext: ShellViewModel
- VolumeViewerView - DataContext: VolumeViewerViewModel

ShellView is the root in my program and it contains 3 VolumeViewerView objects (using their ViewModel instances).

Within each context, things run pretty smooth and as expected.

However, in the VolumeViewerView, I have an `<Image>` whose Cursor I'd like to control from the ShellViewModel.

Here is the code:

ShellView.xaml - `MainView` is an instance of `VolumeViewerViewModel`

```
<Frame  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Content="{Binding MainView}"/>
```

ShellViewModel.cs

```
private Cursor _editorCursor;
public Cursor EditorCursor
{
    get { return _editorCursor; }
    set
    {
        _editorCursor = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => EditorCursor);
    }
}
```

VolumeViewerView.xaml

```
<Image [OTHER PROPERTIES] 
    Cursor="{Binding Path=DataContext.EditorCursor, 
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                     AncestorType={x:Type local:ShellView}}}"/>
```

When I bind the Cursor to a property in VolumeViewerViewModel things work well as expected. But here it isn't connecting.

I've looked for answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717241/binding-property-with-parent-viewmodel), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026342/how-can-i-tell-my-datatemplate-to-bind-to-a-property-in-the-parent-viewmodel/18717026?noredirect=1#comment27579086_18717026), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127933/wpf-databinding-how-do-i-access-the-parent-data-context). But none of them is working.

I wonder, is this even possible given they are in different files? Does `FindAncestor` only work within the context of the same `xaml` file?

If it isn't possible, what is a good alternative? I can create `EditorCursor` inside `VolumeViewerViewModel` and have it set every time the `EditorCursor` in `ShellViewModel` is set, but that looks a bit ugly. If it is the only way, I may just elect to go there. But I would really love suggestions!

Comment: `RelativeSource FindAncestor` works if the elements are in the same visual tree. Is that true for your views?

Comment: @Clemens the view I am trying to do binding in is the `VolumeViewerView` which is loaded in `ShellView` using `Frame`. So they are two different files as I described in the question.

Comment: It does have to do with files. Just whether the elements are in the same visual tree. A Frame is a tree boundary.

Comment: @Clemens Unless `Frame` is the wrong way to embed `VolumeViewerView` I would assume they are in the same tree. Maybe the way I am embedding it is wrong and hence it is unable to find the proper ancestor?

Comment: @Clemens Okay I finally was able to fix it. Initially I had `VolumeViewerView` defined as `Page` which I could not embed in `ContentControl` so I used `Frame` instead. I changed it to `UserControl` and embedded it in `ContentControl` instead of `Frame` and the binding worked. Is there any particular reason why this works?

Comment: As said, Frame is a tree boundary.

Comment: @Clemens I see! I was unaware of that. Thank you! Would you be so kind to just make an answer of that so I could select it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Clemens indicated in the comments, the Visual Tree ends with a `Frame` element. This was the root of my issues. I had put the child view in a `Frame` which meant `FindAncestor` was incapable of finding the parent element and its `DataContext`.

I edited ShellView.xaml, replaced `Frame`:

```
<ContentControl  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Content="{Binding MainView}"/>
```

This meant that I also had to edit the child view (it originally inherited `Page` which cannot be the content of a `ContentControl`). I made it `UserControl` and the binding worked as expected.