# Binding Commands to child ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, commandbinding

I'm trying to figure hot to bind commands from ribbon to content control.

My view look something like this:

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:CityViewModel}">
        <Views:EditorView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:CountryViewModel}">
      <Views:EditorView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:SomeOtherViewModel}">
      <Views:SomeOtherView />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
 <DockPanel>
    <Fluent:Ribbon x:Name="MainRibbon"
                   AutomaticStateManagement="True"
                   DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      <Fluent:RibbonTabItem Header=SomeHeader>
      <Fluent:RibbonGroupBox Header="Actions">
       <Fluent:Button Fluent:RibbonAttachedProperties.RibbonSizeDefinition="Middle,Small"
                      Header="New"
                      Command = "{Binding NewCommand}"
                      CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=SubView}"/>
       <Fluent:Button Fluent:RibbonAttachedProperties.RibbonSizeDefinition="Middle,Small" Header="Save"
                      Command = "{Binding SaveCommand}"
                      CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=SubView}"/>
      </Fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
     </Fluent:RibbonTabItem>
   </Fluent:Ribbon>           
  <ContentControl Name="SubView" Content="{Binding CurentSubView}" />
 </DockPanel>
```

MainViewModel sets CurrentSubView from IOC:

```
CurentSubView = ViewModelFactory.Create<SomeViewModel>();
```

`CityViewModel` and `CountryViewModel` are derived from `EditorViewModel<T>`
 And share basic Actions which have been put to `EditorViewModel<T>` base class

```
 public RelayCommand NewCommand { get; private set; }
 public RelayCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
```

etc....

The question for me is how to expose commands from child viewmodel to ribbon?

As first view model CurrentSubView does not implement those commands so I get "*BindingExpression path error: 'NewCommand' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel'"*.....

I managed to  bind command by some code in my MainViewModel i have added:

```
 private RelayCommand m_newCommand;
 public RelayCommand NewCommand
   {
     get { return m_newCommand; }
   }
```

> ```
>   if (typeof(IEditorViewModel).IsInstanceOfType(CurentSubView))
>   {
>     m_newCommand = ((IEditorViewModel)CurentSubView).NewCommand;
>     RaisePropertyChanged(() => NewCommand);
>   }
>   else
>   {
>     m_newCommand = null;
>   }
> ```

But still opened for more elegant suggestions ;)

Comment: So CityViewModel and CountryViewModel are instantiated in CurrentSubView? Can you set the DataContext of the Fluent:Ribbon to use the correct ViewModel?

Comment: Yes but only only on button click like `<Button Command="{Binding OpenView}" CommandParameter="Cities" Content="Cities" />` and command OpenView is RelayCommand<string> on MainViewModel and this works

Comment: This looks similar to what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026342/how-can-i-tell-my-datatemplate-to-bind-to-a-property-in-the-parent-viewmodel?rq=1

Comment: Yes it is similar to that question but in reverse order Child->Parent. I need Parent-Child command binding

Comment: If you have multiple chile, how should the parent know which child command should be executed?

Comment: MainViewModel at the given moment holds only one active SubViewModel visible so after SubViewModel is taken from IOC I will have a method to bind commands from tab to activated SubViewModel. Only one "RibbonTab" with commands that are shared can be active so it's easy but a lot of possible ugly code :(. Swithing between SubViewModels also include rebinding commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was simple as it can be.
`<fluent:RibbonTabItem/>` has it's on `DataContext` So only needed to be done:

```
<fluent:RibbonTabItem Name="SomeTab" DataContext="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" Header="SomeTab">
```